# How to copy the string referenced by a pointer into another string?

Tags: c++, string

For example, a string pointed by a pointer has the following format

```
msg->data.c_str()
```

Now, I want to stored this string into a "local" string such as:

```
string str = msg->data.c_str();
```

However, this does not work, and I am not so familiar with pointer manipulation. could anyone help?

Comment: Please elaborate the "However, this does not work" part

Comment: `std::string` has [a constructor taking a `const char*`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) as well, so your code should work. However, the approach laid out in my answer is still better and more clear.

Comment: are you expecting something like string str=sring(msg->data.c_str())

Comment: See "[how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" for guidance on how to pose your questions. "this does not work" is not enough to go on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
string str = msg->data;
```

This will call the `std::string` copy constructor with the `msg->data` string as argument. The result is that `msg->data` is safely copied into `str`. Whether the actual contents are copied right away, or if it's copy-on-write is up to the implementation. You don't need to worry about that, it will "just work".

Comment: this will not copy it, it will only point to the data. Manipulating str would directly manipulate msg as well, with this answer.

Comment: @Lstor your example is not relevant since you do another affectation. rici's example is better.

Comment: @Maxime I agree. But the fact of the matter remains, `std::string` copy operations work as expected.

Comment: To whoever downvoted: Please do not downvote a correct answer, at least not without giving a solid explanation.

Comment: @coder543 I think you misunderstand OP's code. `msg` is not a string. `msg` is a something that contains a `std::string` called `data`.

Comment: @coder543 Wrong. C++ uses value semantics not reference semantics like Java. `str` is a `std::string` _value_ not a reference or a pointer therefore a copy will be made.

Comment: @Lstor, i, at least, didn't downvote this answer since even though I thought it was wrong I didn't have time to prove it. It's interesting to see that this does work though. I most definitely did misunderstand the question.

Answer (score 1):

`.c_str()` allows to get a `const char*` from a string. If you are interested in the string directly, just remove `c_str()`.